# autodesk forge message": "this account doesn't exist."

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

i am trying to get all the BIM360 users using postman but unfortunately, i am getting an error:

{
    "code": 1004,
    "message": "this account doesn't exist."
}

[image]

Comment: The most possibility is the account  id is wrong. Did you follow the steps to get account id  https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/getting-started/manage-access-to-docs/. OR you got the id by GET:Hubs of Data Management API?  In addition, if testing with other BIM360 HQ (Admin) API,  can it work? or only failed with GET Users?

Comment: it seems when I am changing to Method and URI (US): i got this message that i need to use 2-logged : 
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


even when i am using the 2 logged i got this error (not that i am account admin at BIM360):
[![enter image description here][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCGJt.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIWWt.png

not i removed the (b.) from the hub_id

Comment: Abed,My apology for the late response! I missed your reply.  If you are still having this problem with 2legged token, could you send us with the Forge client key, and hub id at forge.help@autodesk.com? We will check the http request are backend.

Comment: I am receiving the same error when POSTing to:
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v1/regions/eu/accounts/{AccountId}/projects.

As I understand the AccountId is the hubId and it exists since
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs/b.{AccountId} returns the account info. What am I doing wrong?